# DJango forms that allow you to change the database of a specific user

Tags: python, django, database, forms, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a Django social network application. My function intakes the request from a logged in user and changed their respective details based on the input of their forms.

Forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = AppUser
        fields = ['bio','profileimg']
```

Model.py

```
class AppUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_user = models.IntegerField()
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    profileimg = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', default='blank-profile-picture.png')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

settings.html
<form id="profile_form" method="post" action="/home/"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {% csrf_token %}
    
    {{ profile_form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

This is my current views code:

```
def settings(request):
    user_profile = AppUser.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None, instance=user_profile)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Form is invalid')
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=user_profile)
        
    return render(request, 'settings.html', {'profile_form': profile_form})
```

I tried running the code but nothing happens in the database.

Answer (score 1):

`id_user` is a required field for your `AppUser` model, yet it does not show up in your form fields. This could be the issue.